# How to stop Maven from overwriting if the destination exists

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I have a directory in a dependency, that I want copied in src/main/webapp/mypath during the initialize phase.
But I want it to be copied exactly and only once, meaning that:

- if src/main/webapp/mypath doesn't exist, then copy from dependency
- if src/main/webapp/mypath exists, then never ever copy from dependency even if the one in the dependency is newer. If exists, don't overwrite it. Never.

I tried a couple of approaches with copy-resources and dependency:unpack but maven will **always** overwrite if mypath coming from the dependency is newer / updated even if I set to false every possible overwrite* configuration I'm aware of.

Any advice or RTFM + link to a manual I didn't read so far?

Comment: The question is why do you need such a weird thing?

Comment: The reason is in the nature of the project :) too long to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html):

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <file>
        <missing>src/main/webapp/mypath</missing>
      </file>
    </activation>
    ... copy ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but I have several profiles defined, each with proper activation rules and when I try to add another one with that very same activation rule ( "missing" ), the other profiles don't get activated. I understand that maven (2.2.1) doesn't allow me to activate 2 profiles at the same time, is it true?

Comment: So for me you can use maven-antrun-plugin. See [How to execute tasks conditionally using the maven-antrun-plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1975641/651140)

Comment: Sounds promising! I'll try that tomorrow morning and will come back with the results I'll get :)

Comment: the maven-antrun-plugin did the trick.
I used it to set a property if mypath is missing, and then use that property to set `skip` for dependency:unpack

Comment: This is the main reason why you should never have profiles that execute by default. It fully breaks extendability i.e. adding a child module that has profiles will disable the functionality of your project. Profiles should only be used as a last resort. Your build should be well defined on it's own without profiles. If you are using profiles to create different types of artifacts, I suggest you instead create sub modules that create these on every run, giving you consistent output.

Answer (score 0):

As described by @William, you can use ant plugin, export the property to maven context and skip the task if "true".

Here is the code:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                <target>
                    <available file="src/main/resources/my-data" type="dir"
                                                   property="dir-exits"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-zip-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${dir-exists}</skip>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
                        <includes>**/*.json</includes>                                                       <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```